# What is a "reference current"

Tags: electric-current

Excuse me, I m not a physicist

I am currently reading a paper about optimization on minimizing electrical energy in electrical vehicles. The paper talks about a "reference current" in a current regulator of the motor.

I do not understand what this means, google sends me to pages that have nothing to do with the term. So I am not sure if this is actually a proper term in physics.

The link to the paper is

http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2011/04/2997.pdf

The term in question is in page 5 of the pdf, section 3, in the last sentence of the 2nd paragraph.

Thank you

Comment: Read the wikipedia article on *Voltage Reference* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_reference, and intuitively it seems like *Current Reference* would be analogous.  When I'm routing a circuit board there's a lot of times a voltage reference pin on the various chips.

Comment: But is it allowable to borrow the same context? But thank you, that does dispel some doubt.

Comment: Would http://electronics.stackexchange.com be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reference current is just a stable source of current that does not fluctuate over temperature, supply voltages or loads.  This "reference" is known to be at a specific value and very stable.  This way it can be used to compare other currents to (as a reference).

For example if you want to drive your electric motor at 100A and you know your reference current is a solid 1A then you know when your drive current is 100x more than your reference current it is 100A.

This is what your paper means when they say they are imposing a reference current:

> Our idea, which directly comes from the numerical simulation of the
>   behavior of the vehicle, is to impose during some short sample time
>   the value of the current inside the electrical motor of the vehicle.
>   This is possible using the control parameter u(t). Thus, imposing a
>   reference current iref yields to...

Comment: Oh, so this "reference" can change though? Through the control parameter?

Comment: @sidht The value of the reference current is defined by the hardware design.  In the context of the paper this is why they mention it "comes from numerical simulation of the behavior of the vehicle".  It is unusual to change this dynamically during operation as they are usually static references.